# Imagick Failed to read the file (pdf) but able to read images

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to get Imagick to work because I want to convert PDF to images. I can succesfully open other files but I am unable to open PDF files.

It will give me the error: **Failed to read the file**

Does anyone know how to solve this and -or how to find out what the problem is? I tried different PDF files but none were able to be opened.

- Ubuntu 18.04
- Lumen (newest version)

File is obviously readable and checked with (is_file) et cetera. Everything is fine and working but only PDF files are unable to be opened by Imagick.

```
$imagick = new \Imagick();
$imagick->readImage('/var/www/html/mysite.com/storage/app/files/dummy.pdf');
$imagick->writeImages('/var/www/html/mysite.com/storage/app/files/converted.pdf', false));
```

I tried:

$imagick = new Imagick('/var/www/html/imagick/dummy.pdf');
$imagick = new Imagick('dummy.pdf');

but both give me an error:

```
 Fatal error: Uncaught ImagickException: Failed to read the file in /var/www/html/imagick/index.php:33 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/imagick/index.php(33): Imagick->__construct('dummy.pdf') #1 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/imagick/index.php on line 33
```

When I use a try catch I get this:

```
ImagickException Object
(
    [message:protected] => Failed to read the file
    [string:Exception:private] => 
    [code:protected] => 1
    [file:protected] => /var/www/html/imagick/index.php
    [line:protected] => 13
    [trace:Exception:private] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [file] => /var/www/html/imagick/index.php
                    [line] => 13
                    [function] => __construct
                    [class] => Imagick
                    [type] => ->
                    [args] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => /var/www/html/imagick/dummy.pdf
                        )

                )

        )

    [previous:Exception:private] => 
)
```

Comment: Can you try `$var = file_get_contents('/var/www/html/mysite.com/storage/app/files/dummy.pdf')` and then `$imagick = new \Imagick($var);`? If not, `$imagick->readImageBlob($var);`?

Comment: Unfortunately ain't working. Unable to read image blob is the error I am getting, no matter what PDF I use.

Comment: I found it out... so dumb -_- I had to install Ghost script. That's all! the tutorial I used never told anything about Ghost script, nor did the error message. Anyways, this was the solution ;)   thanks for helping!!!

Comment: @Ometecuthli yep, that helped me too. You may want to post that as an answer, actually! I'd happily upvote :)

Answer (score 0):

First check whether PHP can read the file at all. It could be that this file also has other permissions. file_get_contents returns a string, check its length.

```
$Content = file_get_contents('/var/www/html/mysite.com/storage/app/files/dummy.pdf');
if (strlen($Content) < 10) {
    // content is not readable.
}
```

Is it a **multi-page PDF**?
I always put [0] at the end to load only the first page.

```
$imagick->readImage('/var/www/html/mysite.com/storage/app/files/dummy.pdf'."[0]");
```

Comment: Why was my answer downvoted? 
It would be really helpful for me and for the other users if you write a comment.WHY - what is the reason, why is my answer wrong.